# get count of columns that have a -1, 0, 1, 2 values for a single row

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL Server, I need to get a column count that has -1, 0, 1, 2 for its values for each row.   There are different number of columns per table (one table has 55 fields)

```
-1 value = no answer or unknown (unknown_count)
0  value = ok (ok_count)
1  value = bad  (bad_count)
2  value = not applicable  (na_count)
```

row 1 looks like this

```
rowid        name       field_1       field_2     field_3  field_4
1            line_1     -1            1           2        1
2            line_2     2             1           -1       0
```

etc...

Results i would like to see

```
rowid     na_count     ok_count     bad_count     unknown_count
1         1            0            2             1
2         1            1            1             1
```

Extra credit question....   i need to get a count of all the fields that are used to build the counts (so i can give a percentile report)

Comment: Horrible database design for this! Still doable with an `UNPIVOT` though

Answer (score 2):

You need a combination of [`UNPIVOT`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and some aggregation. Unpivot the data to a more sensible form, and then group by `rowid` summing up the various values:

```
with data AS
(
  select 
    rowid,
    field,
    value
  from
   ( SELECT rowid, field_1,field_2,field_3,field_4
     FROM MyTable) p
  UNPIVOT
    ( value FOR field IN (field_1,field_2,field_3,field_4) ) as unpvt
)
SELECT 
  rowid,
  SUM(CASE WHEN value = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS na_count,
  SUM(CASE WHEN value = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ok_count,
  SUM(CASE WHEN value = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS bad_count,
  SUM(CASE WHEN value = -1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS unknown_count
from data
group by rowId
```

Live example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b702c/1

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer by Jamiec and some code I've used before; If you don't want to type in all the column names in the query you can use dynamic sql to build the query like this:

```
declare @tab nvarchar(max)
set @tab = N'your_table' -- change to your table name

declare @cols nvarchar(max) 
select @cols = coalesce(@cols+N',', N'') + quotename(c.name) from syscolumns c
inner join sysobjects o on c.id = o.id and o.xtype = 'u'
where o.name = @tab 
and c.name not in ('rowid', 'name') -- exclude the columns that don't hold data values
order by c.colid

declare @sql nvarchar(max)  
select @sql = N'
select 
    rowid, 
    sum(case when val = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as ''na_count'',
    sum(case when val = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as ''ok_count'',
    sum(case when val = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as ''bad_count'',
    sum(case when val = -1 then 1 else 0 end) as ''unknown_count'',
    count(*) as column_count
from (select rowid, ' + @cols + N' from ' + @tab + N') as src
unpivot (val for col in (' + @cols + N')) as unpvt
group by rowid'

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: Good enhancement, as long as you realise the execution time will go up by a factor of 10. (My original query: 6ms this query on the same data: 131ms)

Comment: @Jamiec Yes, of course it will be slower, I guess that's the price of having it dynamic. the added work should be in the statement building and not the execution of the statement itself, no? So the added execution time should be minimal and not dependent on the size of the data set. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be more effective to sum up all the columns in a dynamical script, rather than to use unpivot. On one million rows i get 16% vs 84% relative to the batch in the execution plan (this code´s output @query vs the unpivot code).

You can use the same logic to get the percentages of each column. Please let me know if you want me to provide you with code for that as well.

```
--DROP TABLE TMP_Test
CREATE TABLE TMP_Test
(
    rowid INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) 
    , name varchar(10)
    , field_1 INT
    , field_2 INT
    , field_3 INT
    , field_4 INT
)

INSERT INTO TMP_Test
SELECT name = 'line_1', field_1 = -1, field_2=1, field_3=2, field_4=1 
UNION ALL
SELECT name = 'line_2', field_1 = 2, field_2=1, field_3=-1, field_4= 0

/*
WHILE((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TMP_Test) < 1000000)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TMP_Test
    SELECT name, field_1, field_2, field_3, field_4  FROM TMP_Test
END
*/


GO

DECLARE @query VARCHAR(MAX) = '';
DECLARE @schema VARCHAR(128) = 'dbo';
DECLARE @table VARCHAR(128) = 'TMP_Test';

DECLARE @na_count VARCHAR(max) = '';
DECLARE @ok_count VARCHAR(max) = '';
DECLARE @bad_count VARCHAR(max) = '';
DECLARE @unknown_count VARCHAR(max) = '';

SELECT 
@na_count = @na_count + IIF(@na_count = '', '', ' + ') + 'IIF(' + COLUMN_NAME + ' = 2, 1, 0)'
, @ok_count = @ok_count + IIF(@ok_count = '', '', ' + ') + 'IIF(' + COLUMN_NAME + ' = 0, 1, 0)'
, @bad_count = @bad_count + IIF(@bad_count = '', '', ' + ') + 'IIF(' + COLUMN_NAME + ' = 1, 1, 0)'
, @unknown_count = @unknown_count + IIF(@unknown_count = '', '', ' + ') + 'IIF(' + COLUMN_NAME + ' = -1, 1, 0)'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE 
TABLE_SCHEMA = @schema
AND TABLE_NAME = @table
AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('rowid', 'name')
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION;

SET @query = '
SELECT
rowid
, na_count = ' + @na_count + '
, ok_count = ' + @ok_count + '
, bad_count = ' + @bad_count + '
, unknown_count = ' + @unknown_count + '
FROM [' + @schema + '].[' + @table + ']';

PRINT(@query);
EXEC(@query);
```